# Sharepoint 2019 (onpremise) app-only connection thru powershell

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, pnp-powershell, 2019, app

i was able to create an app-only sharepoint (version 2019 on premise) by following this guide https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs .

I don't find any powershell command to connect to the site using the sharepoint app-only created.

I find only powershell command for sharepoint online.

Could you kindly help me? Best regards

Answer (score 0):

if you have PowerShellGet installed, you can run the following commands to install the PowerShell cmdlets:

```
Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShell2019
```

And use the pnp to connect

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/demo -ClientId [Your Client ID] -ClientSecret "[Your Client Secret]"
```